# Wordpress WP-Admin redirection

Tags: wordpress, azure, nginx

I migrated my wordpress site from AWS to Azure, in which all the themes, data and everything was done smoothly.

However, When I now try to login using Wp-admin page, it doesn't login. It simply redirects me to the same page.

I am using nginx as my web server and this is the re-write rule that I have written -

```
location /wp-admin/ {
    #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php /blog$uri;
    #rewrite ^/blog(/.*)$ $1 break;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080/wp-admin/;
}
```

Please help

Comment: Why would add a `/wp-admin/` rule to nginx ?

Comment: Hi Tarun, I am a complete beginner. Any idea has to how to proceed ?